# Why only the ground state term in BE gases?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, bose-einstein-condensate

Usually most texts in statistical physics (e.g. Landau), and many papers I found on the subject, deal with Bose-Einstein statistics in the following manner:

they use an approximation for which the discrete states of the system are approximated by a continuous obtaining the following form for the number of particles in the GC ensemble:
$$ N = \frac{V}{\lambda} \text{Li}_{3/2} (z) \ ,$$
where $z= e^{\mu/KT}$, Li refers to the polylogarithm, and $\lambda$ is the deBroglie wavelenght for the particle in the box $\lambda= \sqrt{2\pi\hbar^2/ mkT}$.
Then they say that the continuous approximation takes incorrectly the particles in the ground state, and add the term
$$N_0 = \frac{z}{1-z} \ ,$$
so that the `real' number of particles is then
$$ N =  \frac{z}{1-z}  + \frac{V}{\lambda} \text{Li}_{3/2} (z) \ ,$$
and follow up calculating $N_0/N$.

However, I might ask, why don't they add more terms, ad the gas approaches condensation  we might have to take discretely the first, or second, or n-th excited states since a large number of particles might still reside in those.  Why it is usually not taken then?

I remember hearing in a seminar that  it has to do with the fact that the number of particles in excited states were of order $1/N$ and therefore can be ignored in the thermodynamic limit. But I never found a paper that explicitly explains that. Does any one here knows the reference?

Thanks in advance

PS: if all excited states have a number of particles of order  $1/N$ how can the particles in the continuous approximation be relevant at all in the thermodynamical limit? I know that the number of possible states can be $\gg N$ but shouldn't the number of particles in excited states go to zero as well?

Comment: Have you tried just computing the value of $N_1$, the occupation of the  first excited state? I seem to remember being set this as homework in undergrad so I don't think its too hard although I don't have a reference immediately to hand.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, there are two possibilities:

1. we use a continuous model, and only take a single discrete level into account, because this single level is absolutely needed,
2. we use discrete levels, and no continuous level structure.

Everything else seams to be more complicates than absolutely needed. The calculations for 1D and 3D can be found here: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.54.656